# CSS - UL inline LI with border alters block (v) inline?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm so confused...so I've got a UL inside a container and it seems like when I alter a DIV above the UL, it impacts the flow after the UL...what is happening?

A DIV is a block element, right?  As is a UL, right?

So in this example, if you remove the "header" DIV, it changes how the H1 element appears after the UL...can anyone help tell me why?

I'm in IE8...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Layout and CSS testing</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 600px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .navMenu {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .navMenu li {
        display:inline;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="images/picture.gif" width="600" height="100" id="headerpic" border="0" />
    </div>
    <ul class="navMenu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1>First Header</h1>
    <h2>Second header</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h1>` is being affected by the navMenu float, try adding a `<div class="clearBoth"></div>` in between the closing `</ul>` and the `<h1>` like so:

html

```
</ul>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
<h1>First Header</h1>
```

css

```
.clearBoth{
   clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Since I didn't have a float defined on the navMenu, is there some sort of default float value?

Comment: The float was defined in the navMenu's list items to be more specific. By default it is turned off, but your navMenu li's have a float:left that needed to be cleared